# Post json data with PHP curl and parameters

Tags: php, json, api, post, curl

can you please help me with this issue.

I need to connect to json API and authenticate (connectorauth) via two parameters - key and connector_id.
Key is the API key, and connector_id is just an id.
I also have a url to extract the data from.

All I know is that I have to get the data via post and curl. Can you please send me an example script to authenticate. I'm not sure how to use the two parameters key and connector_id.

Should I use them in header, or I should use CURLOPT_USERPWD.

On success, I should get this result - [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

`$url` will be the post url
`$params` is query string for eg:- key=somevalue&connector_id=value

`$count` no of parameters passed. Int this example 2 key and connector_id

```
function download_page($url, $count, $params) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $count);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot :)
There was also a problem with the SSL, so I needed to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);